Normalizer of a Young subgroup in symmetric group
In $S_n$, a Young subgroup $S_{r_1}^{m_1}\times S_{r_2}^{m_2}\times ... S_{r_k}^{m_k}$ where $m_1\times r_1+...+m_k\times r_k=n$ has normalizer $N=S_{r_1}wr S_{m_1} \times ...\times S_{r_k}wr S_{m_k}$. Where can I find a reference for this normalizer (maybe a textbook)? Thank you.
